# error in getting latest 10 past events using ethers v5

Tags: solidity, events, ethers.js

I am trying to get latest 10 past events using ethers.js (v5.5.4). below is my code:

```
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(portis.provider);
      const myContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contract.abi, provider);

      let eventFilter = myContract.filters.MyEvent()
      let events = await myContract.queryFilter(eventFilter, -10, "latest") //not working if I specify blocks
      console.log(events)
```

The above code works well if I didn't specify any block numbers in `from` and `to` arguments, but nothing is fetched if I mention block numbers (`-10` and `latest` respectively).

I followed the example provided [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/example/#erc20-events)

Comment: Your queryFilter() asks for all the MyEvent in the last 10 blocks.
Maybe your contract did not fire any event within the last 10 blocks (which is about in the last minute on Ethereum).

Answer (score -1):

Change -10 to 0.
I don't think -10 is a valid argument. Also, there may be limitations on how many blocks you can fetch/query through.

Comment: The parameter -10 is valid. They use it in the documentation linked in the question https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/example/#erc20-events.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/84257)